# How to control when password is required to connect with TeamViewer

Tags: teamviewer

I have three computers that we'll call Main, Sub1, and Sub2.

Using TeamViewer, I want to be able to see and control the desktops of Sub1 and Sub2 from Main any time I want without any input from anybody on Sub1 or Sub2.  I want to do this without having to input a password each time.

I want Sub1 and Sub2 to also be able to connect to and view the desktop of Main, but I want them to have to enter a password before the conneciton is made.

I am indifferent as to how connections are made between Sub1 and Sub2.

Is such a configuration possible?

Currently, on all three computers, I am logged into my TeamViewer account.  All three computers have passwords set up for unattended access.  All three computers are able to easily connect to the desktop of any of the others.

I tried changing the password for Main, but it didn't make a difference -- the other computers are still able to connect to it without ever having to input that password.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, its easy. You already mention that you use your teamviewer account. All you need to do is right-click the account for Main, choose Properties (gear, then properties) and clear the password field.

Now, everytime you connect to Main, it will ask for a password, but Sub1 and Sub2 will connect without a problem.

Note, you also will be prompted to enter a password if you connect from any of the pc's to Main. If you want to be able to connect to Main without entering a password, use 2 teamviewer accounts.

Answer (score -1):

You can set up Unattended access in all the three Teamviewer sessions adding one another as a peer to each other. Open TeamViewer. Click Connection -> Setup unattended access.

It's pretty simple & straight forward.

In the first step set a computer name and password for the remote computer.
In the second step you can add this remote computer to your partner list (refer to “TeamViewer - Use the Partner List“).

Open your partner list and right-click on the computer name you would like
to connect with (see step 2). Choose the connection mode you prefer: remote
control, presentation, file transfer or VPN.

Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.worldstart.com/how-to-set-up-unattended-access-on-your-computer-with-teamviewer/) or [here](http://www.wintips.org/remote-access-control-teamviewer/).

Comment: Even though the answer is correct, it does not answer the question.